# netsuite transform a sales order to cash sale

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I'm trying to transform a sales order in netsuite to a cash sale using nlapiTransformRecord.  According to the docs this should be posible as it is an allowed transform, but I can find no examples of this specific transform anywhere.
Here's an example of what I'm trying to do.

```
var int = 123456;
var rec = nlapiLoadRecord('salesorder', int);
rec.setFieldValue('customform', 123);
```

Start by loading a record.  Now according to the docs, the only required feild for a cash sale that I dont have on the sales order is postingperiod.  Ive tried it with and without setting this field to no avail.  Also customform is just a cash sale custom form.  Obviously ids are not real.

```
rec.setFieldValue('postingperiod', 58);
var cash = nlapiTransformRecord('salesorder', int, 'cashsale', {'postingperiod': 58});
```

Now I've tried setting the the postingperiod value and setting as a default for the transform and both return That is not a valid record transformation.  Anyway here's the line for the transform docs about it be a standard transform.

```
Record Type   Record Name     Transform Type    Transform Name (Target Record)
salesorder    Sales Order     cashsale          Cash Sale
```

Answer (score 3):

You are getting the super helpful "That is not a valid record transformation" error because the payment method on your sales order is not of a "cash" type ie, net terms. As such you are not able to transform it to a cash sale. Either change the payment method to a "cash" type or do your transform to an invoice.  You can test how NS would handle it naively by pressing the bill button from the SO in the UI. Other than that your code / the other recommendations are correct.

Comment: This is the most likely reason for the error mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You would do this as follows:

```
var cash = nlapiTransformRecord('salesorder', int, 'cashsale'); // can initialize with {customform:formId} 
cash.setFieldValue('postingperiod', 58); // assuming 58 is the internal id of an open period
nlapiSubmitRecord(cash);
```

Answer (score 1):

Sales Order is a non-posting transaction, so, below code won't have any effect

```
var int = 123456;
var rec = nlapiLoadRecord('salesorder', int);
rec.setFieldValue('customform', 123);
```

Posting period is automatically set by NetSuite based on transaction date, so, you need not explicitly set it in most cases.

```
var cash = nlapiTransformRecord('salesorder', int, 'cashsale');
```

If you really need to change posting period you , I would suggest transforming record in dynamic mode and then setting trandate  on it, as NetSuite will automatically pull the appropriate posting period.

```
var cash = nlapiTransformRecord('salesorder', int, 'cash sale', {'recordmode': 'dynamic'});
cash.setFieldValue('trandate', APPROPRIATE_TRANDATE_VALUE);
nlapiSubmitRecord(cash);
```

Comment: Actually you can override the posting period independent of tran date. Not a best practice but it's certainly doable.

Comment: agreed. For a script solution I always prefer setting a `trandate` and let NetSuite set `postingperiod` over hardcoding `postingperiod`

Answer (score 0):

Alright turned out one of the guys in our china office had disabled that transform being allowed somehow for a script he was running.  So that was fun.